# Difference between two time using jquery

Tags: jquery

Difference between two time using jquery

I have two times

```
var ftime = "03:00:00"; //retrieved from db
var ltime = "03:10:00"; //retrieved from db
```

Now I want to get the difference between two times in minutes.

What I tried is

```
var ftime = "03:00:00";
var ltime = "03:10:00";
alert(( new Date("1970-1-1"+  ltime ) - new Date("1970-1-1"+ ftime ))/1000/60);
```

but this alerts **NaN**

My desired result is `10`

Any help is really appreciable...

Comment: You missed space after `"-1"`, i.e. shouldve been `new Date("1970-1-1 "+  ltime )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the space after the date (1970-1-1).
Try this:

```
alert(( new Date("1970-1-1 "+  ltime ) - new Date("1970-1-1 "+ ftime ))/1000/60);
```

Comment: These small errors happens all the time. You are welcome :-)